# Accessing/using elements from lists of tuples python 3.x

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop, tuples

I'm new to python and I'm trying to figure out how to access and use integers stored in lists of tuple pairs (a, b), such that I can divide a by b and if it meets a criteria, I append the tuple to a new list and I count the tuple. I would like to do this using only basic functions and for-loops.

I borrowed some code from another stackoverflow question that I used to create the list of tuples from two separate integer lists of different sizes as such:

```
list_a = list(range(10, 51))

list_b = list(range(1, 21))

new_tuple_list = []
new_tuple_count = 0

for i, a in enumerate(list_a):
    new_tuple_list.append((a, list_b[i % len(list_b)]))
    divisors_count += 1

print ("New tuple count: ", new_tuple_count)
print (new_tuple_list)
```

This gives me:
New tuple count:  41

```
[(10, 1), (11, 2), (12, 3), (13, 4), (14, 5), (15, 6), (16, 7), (17, 8), (18, 9), (19, 10), (20, 11), (21, 12), (22, 13), (23, 14), (24, 15), (25, 16), (26, 17), (27, 18), (28, 19), (29, 20), (30, 1), (31, 2), (32, 3), (33, 4), (34, 5), (35, 6), (36, 7), (37, 8), (38, 9), (39, 10), (40, 11), (41, 12), (42, 13), (43, 14), (44, 15), (45, 16), (46, 17), (47, 18), (48, 19), (49, 20), (50, 1)]
```

But I want to know if I divide 10 by 1 from (10, 1), 11 by 2, etc., will I get an integer, and if so, I want to add that to a new list and count the number of tuple pairs this is true for. 
I have tried this:

```
tuple_test = [(10,1), (11,2)]
def find_divisors (x):

    NUM_tuples = []
    tuples_count = 0

    for x[0] in pairs:
        for x[1] in pairs:
            if x[0] / x[1] % 2 == 0:
                NUM_tuples.append(pairs)
                tuples_count += 1
                return (x[0] / x[1] % 2)
    return NUM_tuples
    return tuples_count

 find_divisors(tuple_test)
```

I have also tried something like this:

```
def divisors(list_a, list_b):

    test_int = 0
    new_divisors = []

    for a in list_a:
        for b in list_b:
            if a/b % 2 == 0:
                test_int += 1
                new_divisors += (a,b)

    return new_divisors
    return test_int

    NUM_tuples = []
    tuples_count = 0


    for i, c in enumerate(list_a):
        NUM_tuples.append((c, list_b[i % len(list_b)]))
        tuples_count += 1
    return tuples_count
    return NUM_tuples

divisors(list_a, list_b)
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use `list(zip(list_a, list_b))` to combine the lists. It's much more basic that way.

Comment: Please double check your indentation. As written it looks like you've written two `return` statements on consecutive lines, for example, and then continued the function after that anyway. If that's actually the code you've written, then you need to review a tutorial.

Comment: @MadPhysicist `zip` in his case does not work because zip will stop at `(29,20)` since his list_b only has 20 values. But if you check his result, it continued after that with `(30,1)` and so on.

Comment: I need to assess every combination of list_a and list_b even though the lists are of two different lengths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following :

```
a = range(1,20)
b = range(1,5)
c = [(x,y) for x in a for y in b if x%y==0]
print(c)
```

It gives the following output

```
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1), (3, 3), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 4), (5, 1), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (7, 1), (8, 1), (8, 2), (8, 4), (9, 1), (9, 3), (10, 1), (10, 2), (11, 1), (12, 1), (12, 2), (12, 3), (12, 4), (13, 1), (14, 1), (14, 2), (15, 1), (15, 3), (16, 1), (16, 2), (16, 4), (17, 1), (18, 1), (18, 2), (18, 3), (19, 1)]
```

You can easily adapt this for your program I think !!

PS : The length of `c` above will give you the tuple count.

Comment: This is fantastic and simply elegant! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to add that you can reduce your code to get the original list of tuples to the following using [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle).

```
from itertools import cycle

# a and b don't have to be a list unless you need them as a list elsewhere.
a = range(10, 51)
b = range(1, 21)
# cycle the shorter one
tuple_lst = list(zip(a, cycle(b)))

print("New tuple count:", len(tuple_lst))
print(tuple_lst)
```